# Folder Redirection Not Working With Loopback Processing

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy, loopback, folder-redirection

I have an OU named TEST-OU where I want to apply Folder Redirection to all users in that OU. So far this has been working fine.

Next I created a sub-OU below that one called TEST-SUBOU where I want to exclude all servers from having the folder redirection applied by enabling a loopback policy.

The loopback policy is working fine but now it is causing the Folder Redirection GPO to not work anymore.

When I unlinked the loopback policy GPO the Folder Redirection GPO started working again.

Any idea how the loopback policy might be affecting the Folder Redirection GPO? I thought if it is linked in the sub-OU it only affects items in that OU?

[image: Folder Redirection GPO]

Answer (score 0):

Check the security filtering for the Lookback Policy and have it apply only to the server group. 
Also check whether the Lookback Policy is not linked to any other higher OU

Comment: I checked and it is only linked to the TEST-SUBOU. I don't have a server group.

Should I create a Security Group called Domain Servers and add all my servers to that group then change the Security Filtering on the Loopback Processing GPO to the Domain Servers group?

Comment: I would give that a try.